# MethodNotAllowedHttpException, redirect to 404 Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

So when a user randomly types a URL on a route that exists, they get an error message:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

After doing some searching, all the posts I can find suggest to change the render function inside of App\Exceptions\Handler and change it to this:

```
 public function render($request, Exception $exception)
 {
    if($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException){
      return abort('404');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
 }
```

However, with the newer version of Laravel this no longer exists. One post mentioned to add this in routes\web.php:

```
Route::fallback( function () {
    abort( 404 );
} );
```

This works fine but I'm not sure if this is the best approach/right place to have it? Is there are any other alternative way?

I have also attempted to change the register function inside of App\Exceptions\Handler to this per the Laravel Doc (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors#rendering-exceptions):

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

 public function register()
    {
        $this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $e, $request) {
            if ($request->is('api/*')) {
                return response()->json([
                    'message' => 'Record not found.'
                ], 404);
            }
        });
    }
```

but it does not work

Comment: The function exists in Handler.php, but by default it's using the one in `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php`. You can add your own function as above to override it

Comment: @aynber I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Are you able to elaborate please?

Comment: Just because it isn't there doesn't mean it can't be there. `App\Exceptions\Handler` extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler`, which does contain a `render()` function. If you add the `render` function that you found to your Handler.php (changing `render($request, Exception $exception)` to `render($request, Throwable $e)` to match the parent's call), then it should work

Comment: The `render` function inside of Handler.php already is `render($request, Throwable $e)` It was there by default @aynber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a newer version on Laravel, you can add

```
$this->renderable(function (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException $e) {
       // do something
});
```

this line inside a `register` method on a class `\App\Exceptions\Handler`

If you want to handle NotFoundException you should use

```
$this->renderable(function (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $e) {
     // do something
});
```

You can find more detailed answer on Laravel documentation here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors#rendering-exceptions

Comment: I have already tried to do this as shown in my original post but it does not work

Comment: @TildaMendozae you checked for Not Found exception. You should check for Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException not NotFoundException or we can say see an exception class on your stacktrace and handle it